# Dragging files informations with Firefox & JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firefox, file-upload, drag-and-drop

When the user is dragging some file over the drop area, I want to show him a message saying "This file is ok, just drop it" or "This is not an image file, please choose a valid image".

I succeeded to do it with Chrome using event.dataTransfer.items[0] giving me some file informations but with Firefox, It should be possible with event.dataTransfer.files[0] according to the documentation :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/File_drag_and_drop 
But in fact, files list is always null and I am unable to get these informations.

Unfortunately, this is not a standard API, so checking will stay optional (only if available).